# Positioning the TikZ node slightly below the linage

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-node

In the output of the code below, the node is positioned on top the linage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt} 

\begin{document}

Here we are trying to animate an internet forum. A user named \emph{Brico} sends a comment. Here it is:
% Here is my futile attempt to lower the node by 1cm =>  [yshift=-1cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}[yshift=-1cm]\node[color=blue,fill=blue,scale=1.0,transform shape] at (0,0.5){\color{white} @Brico};\end{tikzpicture} % The node options may be redundant! 
\, I think Internet is becoming an unfree place each passing day.
% I've added the [below=-0.2cm] to the  node options. No luck.
\end{document}
```

I'd like to position it slightly below the linage so as to
center the linage like that:

[image]

I've tried several solutions, none worked. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of how to align the base of a node with the surrounding text on page 129 of the TikZ user guide

[image]

Applied to your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt} 

\begin{document}

Here we are trying to animate an internet forum. A user named \emph{Brico} sends a comment. Here it is:
% Here is my futile attempt to lower the node by 1cm =>  [yshift=-1cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(foo.base)]\node[color=blue,fill=blue,scale=1.0,transform shape] (foo) at (0,0.5){\color{white} @Brico};\end{tikzpicture} % The node options may be redundant! 
\, I think Internet is becoming an unfree place each passing day.
% I've added the [below=-0.2cm] to the  node options. No luck.
\end{document}
```

[image]